# Python, float error: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'list'

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

I have set the following class:

```
class StatoPatrimoniale(models.Model):
    reference_date=models.DateField()
    cassa=models.DecimalField()
```

And I have set the following function:

```
def stato_patrimoniale(request):
    now=datetime.datetime.now()
    last_account_year=float(now.year)-1
    list_diff=[]
    list_diff = float(StatoPatrimoniale.objects.filter(reference_date__year=last_account_year).values_list('cassa')[0][0])
```

But python give me the following error:

```
 unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'list'
 list_diff = float(StatoPatrimoniale.objects.filter(reference_date__year=last_account_year).values_list('cassa')[0][0])
```

Why? Where is the issue?

Comment: It is probably wrong, but perfectly allowable and not the cause of this error

Comment: and how could I solve it?

Comment: What does the full stack trace look like?

Comment: In which sense?

Comment: I want to extract the value of cassa object from the class StatoPatrimoniale. It must to be a decimal value.

Comment: nobody could help me?

Comment: Your provided code won't generate an exception as you said

Comment: Why do you create list_diff = [] while next line you set it to a float? You might be using the list_diff later in your code again where you are trying to + it to a float, that gives this error

Comment: Again, please provide the *full* stack trace from the exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reproduced the error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'list'
```

but not with the code shared above. Instead I put:

```
list_diff = float() + list_diff
```

list_diff is a list and float() is float, you can't do that

Replace it by

```
list_diff.append(float())
```